# How to set Eureka URL from code at client application startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, initialization, netflix-eureka

We need to set Eureka server URL at client application from startup code, but it seems there is no way how to do it.

We have a mechanism how to discover Eureka server on network by UDP multicast broadcasting. Server sends response back to the client with information about IP address and port where Eureka server is running. But we don't know how to set this URL in Eureka client application from code. It seems the only way how to set Eureka server URL is the property `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` in application.property file.

```
    // Server - start a new thread with UDP packet detection and reply mechanism
    LocationService.listenAndReplyToEurekaClients(thisServerPort);

    // Server - application start
    SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
```

```java
    // Client - send UDP packet and receive reply with Eureka server IP and port
    Response response  = LocationService.findEurekaServerAddress(5, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    var hostProtocol = "http";

    var eurekaUrl = new URL(
            hostProtocol,
            response.getEurekaAddress(),
            response.getEurekaPort(),"").toString();
```

We would like to set this eurekaURL to the client before it starts registering to Eureka server.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we can do following things-

Extend ***EurekaClientConfigBean*** and override ***getEurekaServerServiceUrls*** method. Method returns a List of String which is nothing but list of all the URLS, of eureka instances. You need to set the URL here from your response which has IP and port.

Later create the discovery client using- ***DiscoveryClient(ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager, EurekaClientConfig config)***. (Its going to be a Bean for sure).

That should work.

You can create **ApplicationInfoManager** as-

```
ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager =
        initializeApplicationInfoManager(webAppInstanceConfig);
```

Where **WebAppInstanceConfig** is-

```
class WebAppInstanceConfig extends MyDataCenterInstanceConfig {// Override all the needed properties from MyDataCenterInstanceConfig}
```